# Default implementation for virtual method in derived class

Tags: c++, function, class, oop, inheritance

I have a base class and a couple of derived classes. The derived classes have common methods, for example an `activate()` or an `init()` which are implemented in slightly different ways. So, i make `activate()` and `init()` pure virtual.

Then, there are methods like `doSomething()` that 90% of derived classes use in different ways. The other 10% do not need that function.

Is it a reasonable practice to inherit `doSomething()` like the following?

The base class:

```
class base { 
public:
virtual void activate() = 0;
virtual void init() = 0;
virtual void doSomething(){ /* internal log that the function is not implemented */ };
};
```

And the derived classes:

```
class derivedA: public base {
public:
virtual void activate() override { /* activate A */ };
virtual void init() override { /* init A */ };
virtual void doSomething() override { /* do something in A */ };
};

//class derivedB to class derivedI like class derivedA

class derivedJ: public base {
public:
virtual void activate() override { /* activate J */ };
virtual void init() override { /* init J */ };
// doSomething() is not overriden and the implementation of base is used
};
```

Is this a possible way to do it or is there maybe a problem with the modelling?

Comment: Yes. Please read a good [C++ programming book](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/), read about [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)-s, ( compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -g` witrh [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org)...), run your code in a debugger step by step to understand what is happening.

Comment: Recommended reading: [Interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but note that it is *possible* to include a definition for a pure-virtual function. It's only useful for explicit super calls though.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Are you sure you're commenting the right question? This is a language agnostic problem. C++-specific implementation details are highly irrelevant here.

Comment: [Visitor_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) might interest you as alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there maybe a problem with the modelling?

Definitely!

I expect that since `derivedJ` inherits from `base`, then `doSomething()` is meant to be used (it doesn't matter which implementation).

However, you want your `derivedJ` class to not provide this method, thus you should change your modelling.

A naive solution would be to modify your `base` class, removing that function, like this:

```
class base { 
public:
  virtual void activate() = 0;
  virtual void init() = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If at least one class derived from `base` does not need, conceptually, to implement `doSomething()`, then `doSomething()` should not be part of `base`'s interface, and so it needs to go into another interface.

That is, `doSomething()` should be part of another abstract base class, call it `base2`.

If `doSomething()` could (or should) not be used separately from `activate()` and `init()`, derive `base2` from `base` and derive `derivedA` to`derivedI` from `base2`, and `derivedJ` from `base`.

If it could, leave `base2` it as a separate class and derive `derivedA` to`derivedI` from both `base` and `base2`, and only derive `derivedJ` from `base`.